# How to make React360 Vrmode work on ios device?

Tags: virtual-reality, react-360

I want to make **React360 split scene** work on an ios device, I have tried to use **webvr-polyfill** , but I dont know how to use it

sorry for my language, I am not a  native speaker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How exactly did you try to use the webvr-polyfill? You will need this since iOS does not natively support it.

Simply include the [webvr-polyfill](https://github.com/immersive-web/webvr-polyfill) in your index.html. Add the webvr-polyfill bevor you run any kind of react-360 code. Example:

```
<script src='PATH_TO_YOU_POLYFILL_FILE/webvr-polyfill.min.js'></script>
<script>var polyfill = new WebVRPolyfill();</script>

<script src="./client.bundle?platform=vr"></script>
<script>
    // Initialize the React 360 application
    WebVR.init(
        'index.bundle?platform=vr&dev=true',
        document.getElementById('container'),
        {
            assetRoot: 'static_assets/',
        }
    );
</script>
```

Comment: I have the same problem, but I used the npm version of the library  

```> npm install --save webvr-polyfill```  

```import WebVRPolyfill from 'webvr-polyfill';
     const polyfill = new WebVRPolyfill();```  

But I have this error Uncaught ReferenceError: mimeType is not defined   
Here the example:  

https://danilodelfio.github.io/MeVR/

Comment: I am having same problem included webvr-polyfill.min.js but it is not working for me. Do we have any other way deal with?